# Importing SQL database to live server, tables missing

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Okay, so first of all, I am SO sorry if this is an ignorant and stupid question. I have absolutely no knowledge of databases. I have only used them when creating and uploading Wordpress sites, and it works if everything goes without any errors.

So here is my problem:

I've created a Wordpress website on a local server. I've done the usual, exported the database, tried to upload it on the live server, but there seems to be an error.

I get the #1064 error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 59

Half of the tables do not import on the live server. Here's what I've already tried:

- Exporting the tables with the "Enclose export in a transaction" and "Disable foreign key checks" checked.
- Exporting in two files with and without the mentioned options checked. This way I got more tables, and the wp_options table got
  full instead of empty, but still only 15 tables instead of 23.
- I checked to see if the "TYPE" syntax is "ENGINE" and it seems fine to my unknowing eyes.

I am a total ignorant when databases are concerned. I don't know what to check anymore. My guess is that the live server uses MariaDB and it is somehow not compatible with the SQL I'm trying to upload.

I tried to see the line 59, but there is no "?" there, at least not where I'm looking at. It might be that I'm looking at the wrong place, the blond that I am.

Here's the code around the line 59 when database is opened in editor.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_gg_folders`
--

CREATE TABLE `wp_gg_folders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I tried to see the MariaDB's documentation and the possible way to deal with any incompatibility would be to update my MySQL. I have no idea how to do it. 
Oh and btw. I already have a working website on this server but with an older version of Wordpress, so if it's an old SQL version, why is it working there?

This turned out to be long... sorry. And thanks in advance!

Edit: I discovered there is a problem with exporting. In the exported file, there are always last third of the tables missing. I have no idea why. Can I somehow get the tables/whole database manually, and not through PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys and girls, I've found the solution.

The problem was not in any error, it was in exporting the database at the very beginning, therefore, importing showed different kinds of errors each time I tried to import the database.

The query, while exporting would abort the export causing only part of the tables to be exported. By changing the length of the query while doing the export, I solved the problem.

Instead of 50000, I wrote in 1047551.

Here's the article that helped me, with screenshots:
https://wpengine.com/support/exporting-database/